# After model conversion the model details missing

Tags: hololens, azure-object-anchors

I use Azure object anchor service to convert a geometry model with obj format. This model is a human head model. Before conversion, the nose, ear and eyes are clearly present in the model. But after conversion, all these details are missing. What I obtained is a very coarse head model. Due to the missing of the details, the detection result is not accurate. I would like to know how to keep the details as I do model conversion?

Thanks.

YL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one, it is likely the model size is just too small.  A human head would be much smaller than the 1-meter threshold.  The service requires larger objects per the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/object-anchors/overview#asset-requirements

"Each dimension of an asset should be **between 1 meter** to 10 meters, and the file size should be less than 150 MB."